How can a distributed system satisfy CP in CAP theorem?
If a system is partition tolerant, it's impossible for it to be consistent since there's no way for one node to update another. How can you be both consistent while partition intolerant be possible?

Re: "there's no way for one node to update another": If the system is unavailable (doesn't support A during a P), then why would one node need to update another?

@ruakh Are you saying that not available implies consistency? It doesn't matter if it's available or not, the data still need to be consistent

It's not that "not available" implies consistency, but that it allows consistency. If the system is consistent until the network partition, and doesn't allow writes during the network partition, then it can remain consistent until it starts allowing writes again.

@ruakh I see makes sense thanks
